# Facebook open graph like button

Tags: facebook

How do I get the facebook open graph admin button to appear on my website? I've have all of the meta data filled out and have ran it through their linter,

Answer (score 0):

Use [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to get the code for your Facebook Like button, and then add that code to your page (Assuming you know how to do this. If not, I can help you there).